# Removing Debian Installation Prompt

Tags: debian, system-installation, data-cd

I attempted to install Debian through a CD, with the initial .exe working fine. However, when I rebooted and went through the installation procedure, my system could not tell that there was a disk there (or the media was unreadable). Now whenever I boot up my computer, I get the choice between continuing on to windows or to complete my installation. How do I remove that choice? Do I have to go through BIOS or are the files on my Windows partition?

Comment: What initial .exe? AFAIK Debian doesn't supply Windows executables, and I don't see it listed on their downloads page (although I'll admit I only skimmed it). Where did you get it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Although, via `msconfig` I couldn't find the "continue with the installation" partition in my disk as a start up thread, nor with disk management, the solution is really simple:

1. Open command prompt: `cmd`
2. Type `bcdedit` (as Marcos suggested)
3. You will find the booting partitions (this term doesn't really exist)
4. Spot the partition that says "Continue with installation" as a description
5. Copy its `{identifier}` (yeah, that long number)
6. Finally, type `bcdedit /delete {identifier}`, where in the place of identifier you have to put the identifier you selected. (Make sure to keep the identifier between braces `{..}` ).

This worked for me in Windows 7 so I guess it can do the job in most of the systems.

Comment: don't forget to put the curled braces around the number {number}

Comment: I am always wondering why answers like these are so hard to find if not for stackexchange.

Comment: I had to put double quotes around the {identifier}

Comment: This worked on Windows 10. Just make sure to open the command prompt in Administrator mode. (Shift Right click on menu item)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. Worked for me on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Debian puts an entry into the Windows Boot Manager for itself and it's partitions. You will need to edit the Windows Boot Configuration Store to remove the incomplete Debian entry. You should be able to edit the Store via msconfig (GUI) or bcdedit (Command line).